# Sending information gathered from questionnaire to a Python document?

Tags: python

I'm brand new to both Python and StackOverflow, and I have a problem that has been stumping me for the past couple of hours.

I am making a peer-evaluation script for my high-school class. When you run the script, you input your classmate's name, then you rate them 1-10 on effort, accountability, and participation. These 3 values are then averaged. This average is assigned to the variable "grade". Since each classmate is going to get multiple grades, I need to have the "grade" variable export to another Python document where I can average every grade for each respective classmate.

So far, I have the script create a .txt file with the same name as the evaluated classmate, and the grade integer is stored there. Does anyone know of a way that I can export that integer to a Python file where I can append each successive grade so they can then be averaged?

Thanks

## Python peer evaluation script

def script():
    classmate = input('Please enter your classmate\'s name: ')

```
classmateString = str(classmate)

effortString = input('Please enter an integer from 1-10 signifying your classmate\'s overall effort during LLS: ')

effort = int(effortString)

accountabilityString = input('Please enter an integer from 1-10 signifying how accountable your classmate was during LLS: ')

accountability = int(accountabilityString)

participationString = input('Please enter an integer from 1-10 signifying your classmate\'s overall participation: ')

participation = int(participationString)

add = effort + accountability + participation 

grade = add / 3

gradeString = str(grade)

print ('Your grade for ', classmate, 'is: ', grade)

print ('Thank you for your participation. Your input will help represent your classmate\'s grade for the LLS event.')

filename = (classmateString)+'.txt'

file = open(filename, 'a+')

file.write(gradeString)

file.close()

print ('Move on to next classmate?')
yes = set(['yes','y','Yes','Y'])
no = set(['no','n','No','n'])

choice = input().lower()
if choice in yes:
    script()
elif choice in no:
    sys.exit(0)
else:
    sys.stdout.write("Please respond with 'yes' or 'no'")
script()
```

script()

Comment: Its better to share code than explaining everything

Answer (score 0):

put

```
import name_of_script_file
```

at the top of your Python file, assuming they are in the same folder.

Then you can access the variable like:

```
name_of_script_file.variable_name
```